# If I want to show the strength of protein-protein interaction, is a networking model appropriate?

Tags: cytoscape

I am doing an experiment where I'm measuring the interaction between PAIRS of proteins in a network. I also have a positive and negative control to show the "least" and "most" amount of interaction that the proteins can possibly have.

I want to do a network model, but am unsure of how I can show the strength of the interactions using numerical data. For example, if the positive control has "50" and negative control "5" (I'm using Miller units), how to use a color gradient to show the strength of the protein-protein interaction I'm investigating.

Would this link "Visualizing Expression Data on Networks" be an appropriate protocol? https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/basic-data-visualization/#/3

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a one-tailed gradient on your edges -- probably using either one of the Viridis palettes or ColorBrewer sequential.  I would probably also use a width gradient to emphasize the interaction strength.